# Skin folder removed in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to make anew Theme for Magento 2 but I can't find the skin folder ?? or where I can edit my the theme CSS.

here my new theme structure

```
TestVender/
└── TestTheme
    ├── etc
    ├── media
    │   └── TestPreview.jpg
    ├── registration.php
    ├── theme.xml
    └── web
        ├── css
        ├── images
        └── js
```

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento2 comes with huge changes on the frontend.

In terms of theme, there are two significant changes we can see in Magento 2 including:

• Removal of skin directory from the root.

• Introduction of a new directory ‘view’ in the module folder structure which actually completes the MVC structure in more structured way.

One do not have to create a directory inside skin directory like one did in Magento 1.x,. Instead, can place all the module specific JS, CSS, Images inside the web directory in each module folder.

Themes are grouped by ‘vendor’ which were known as ‘package’ in magento 1.x. Theme structure in Magento 2 is like ‘app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name’.

Comment: :D nice , 
- why i cant find the home block when i active my new theme from configuration !!
 " can place all the module specify JS, CSS, Images inside the web directory " you mean in pub folder ?

Comment: I don't get it... In Magento 1 I had an image stored in `/skin/frontend/base/default/black/Newsletter2Go/img/ajax-loader.gif`, where do I have to put it in Magento 2 ?